# how to add error class on an input and override style with scss?

Tags: reactjs, sass

this is my css:

```
input[type="text"] {
      .has-error {
        color: red;
        border: 1px solid red;
      }
    }

    input[type="text"],
    textarea {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      border: 1px solid #446a63;
      outline: none;
    }
```

this is my react code:

```
<input
  className={classNames({
    "has-error": true,
  })}
  type="text"
  placeholder="Name"
  value={values.name}
  onBlur={handleBlur("name")}
  onChange={handleChange("name")}
/>
```

but that don't work, this does, but only changes the color and not override the border?, i want to override the border above of it and also nest it inside input type since it's only specific for inputs?:

```
input[type="text"],
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #446a63;
  outline: none;
}

.has-error {
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS, the selector for `input[type="text"]` is more specific than one for just a css class as `.has-error`. Therefore the tag style overrides the class style (you should be able to see this in your dev console).

[image]

So you could fix your code with a more explicit selector, directly referencing both tag and class:

`input[type="text"].has-error,textarea.has-error`

```
input[type="text"],
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #446a63;
  outline: none;
}

input[type="text"].has-error,
textarea.has-error {
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```